# How fast will bullet hit the ground if it is shot vertically?

Tags: projectile

The bullet can be normal AK-74 or M4 bullet. I am just interested to know how much speed it loses due to friction.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_velocity

Comment: Shot to the ground or up to the sky?

Comment: If it's shot to the ground it will logically hit it with the speed it has left the barrel so of course up to the sky

Comment: The speed it hits the ground with is not the same as the speed it came out of the barrel with, if aimed at the ground. It depends on the distance of the barrel and the ground. It could slow down(or up, if it came out really slow).

Comment: I mean the difference would be such a small number that it wouldn't really matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Approximate estimation for an AK-47 bullet

[Terminal velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_velocity) formula is :

[image]

*[Bullet parameters from 7.62×39mm cartridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7.62%C3%9739mm):*

- Mass 0.0079 kg
- Length 0.0268 m
- Diameter 0.0079 m
- Drag coefficient ~ 0.125 of [G7 projectile model](http://www.appliedballisticsllc.com/Articles/ABDOC130_CDM.pdf) under bullet sub-sonic speeds < 1 mach

*Bullet projected area calculation:*

- Minimum projected area is bullet's cross-section, i.e. circle area 0.000049016699 m^2
- Maximum projected area is `length*diameter` 0.00021172 m^2
- Average projected area is `0.6*min_area + 0.4*max_area` 0.000114098020 m^2

Why we need averaged projected area ? Because bullet when falling down experiences [tumbling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e7uZJx8wOrg) (in case shot vertically), so projected area will switch from a minimum value to a maximum value and vise-versa over time. Thus we need projected area averaging.

Second note - maximum area will not be strictly a rectangle, that's why I've used 0.6, 0.4 weights (instead of 0.5,0.5) for an area averaging so that averaged area would be *slightly shifted* to a minimum value.

Plunging all the numbers into the formula gives the answer of
**94    m/s**.

Notes :

- In general drag coefficient depends on bullet speed. For speeds under 1 mach drag coefficient is a constant. I made an assumption that falling bullet
  will not reach super-sonic speeds. It may be true, but not verified
- Drag force depends on flow density, in this case air density. Air density is a function of an altitude. And density is smaller at higher altitude, thus making drag force smaller. So either it will make terminal speed of the bullet bigger or at least bullet will reach terminal velocity faster. Either way, calculations should be more complex than this.

Comment: Once a bullet has reached maximum height it starts to come back down, but does that mean it has stopped rotating? So is it certain it will be tumbling? Tumbling is usually due to an out-of-balance force...

Comment: Of course i'm not certain, that was just an assumption. It may rotate, but don't forget that when bullet will reach maximum height - it will start falling down with blund-end directed forward. So rotation may not have stabilizing effect as it would in case of forward-trip.

Comment: So you assume it travels perfectly perpendicular? as if it goes up with **any** slight angle it will travel in a parabola...

Comment: Question was about `if shot vertically`, so it itself assumes 90° direction with ground normal. Otherwise, I agree on parabola trajectory

Comment: The question actually mentions an AK-74 bullet which is smaller.

Comment: @rghome Can you give exact references instead of simply grumble ? When you do so -  I will fix parameters sheet with a reference link and I'll re-calculate terminal velocity.

Comment: @Agnius Vasiliauskas https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5.45%C3%9739mm. Perhaps keep the old calculation as It would be interesting to compare the two.

Answer (score 3):

The bullet will go upwards until stopped by a combination of gravity and air resistance. It will then fall and reach a terminal velocity (maximum speed) which is the speed where the air resistance matches the force of gravity.

The Wikipedia article on [celebratory gunfire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celebratory_gunfire) states:

> Firearms expert Julian Hatcher studied falling bullets in the 1920s
>   and calculated that .30 caliber rounds reach terminal velocities of 90
>   m/s (300 feet per second or 186 miles per hour). A bullet traveling
>   at only 61 m/s (200 feet per second) to 100 m/s (330 feet per second)
>   can penetrate human skin.

A .30 calibre round is 7.62mm whereas AK-74 and M4 carbines fire 5.45/5.56mm rounds. The lighter rounds will fall more slowly due to higher air resistance compared with weight. They also weigh a lot less (I think about 3 times less, but it will depend on the round - I am sure the gun experts will correct me here if I am too specific). So they will be a lot less lethal.

Comment: so even if bullet directly hits someones head it wont be able to penetrate skull right?

Comment: I am no expert on that, but from what the quote says, it seems borderline for a ,30 cal bullet, so I would say less likely for a lighter round. However, the article makes it clear that people do die from celebratory gunfire, and regularly. It says that bullets fired at an angle are more lethal, so perhaps this is most of the cases.

Comment: @Saba This site is about physics. If you want to draw examples involving permanent injury and death then you may do so, but it seems to me that you need to earn the right to do so by providing something to show that you have taken into consideration the wider human context of your question. This will raise the level of discussion and prevent it from descending into idle curiosity about violent death.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the data used in these equations do not consider that a bullet fired upwards will eventually stop ‘rifling’ and begin tumbling and veer considerably ‘off course’. It will stop its upward motion sooner as a tumbling bullet has much greater air resistance. The same is true as it falls back to Earth. A typical .30 cal bullet would therefore be much lower in speed a terminal velocity, reaching 100-105 mph.

Answer (score 0):

In layman's terms.

A bullet, shot from a gun, dropped from a building, or thrown up by hand, will all fall with the same **acceleration**. How it goes up is irrelevant to how it falls. A bullet, like any other object, will reach the end of its ascent, due to gravity, at which point, it will begin a free fall.

It will usually tumble, or descend sideways, thus creating a greater gravity pull on it. Like everything else falling from a complete stop, it is dependent on its mass, weight and atmospheric (air, or wind) pressure. The average descent velocity of a bullet is approximately 100mph, which is not enough to kill, but can leave a nasty lump and bruising.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Re, "...all fall with the same acceleration." Yes, Specifically, they all fall with _zero_ acceleration. Terminal velocity is _constant_ velocity. Once any falling object reaches its terminal velocity, its acceleration will be zero.

Comment: Re, "...sideways, thus creating a greater gravity pull on it." Is that why it’s so hard to get out of bed in the morning? I weigh more when I'm horizontal?

Comment: "It will usually tumble, or descend sideways, thus creating a greater gravity pull on it" - greater compared to what ? This appears to be claiming that the weight of the bullet depends on its orientation, which is incorrect.